# Avoid deadlock in SSAS by preventing querying during process

Tags: sql-server, ssas, deadlock, olap, cube

I have a **SSAS cube** which is **processed** on a regular basis to integrate newly available data in source tables.

The issue is that sometimes it seems that the process interferes with some heavy queries causing **locking conflicts**. (one every 2 weeks)

How can I avoid that?

Is there a way to prevent SSAS from executing queries while it is processing the cube?

This should not impact performance too heavily as the processing time is quite short in general.

Moreover redesigning the cube to enhance performance and reduce the odds of this issue happening is not an option.

Answer (score 0):

How about you kill all connections to SSAS by closing the firewall. I think the Disable-NetFirewallRule PowerShell command would do that. Then process the cube from the local box. Then enable the firewall rule again.

The other less drastic approach would be to code a "query governor" which would monitor running queries during processing and cancel any that run more than say 30 seconds. This blog post would give you a pattern to follow:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/johndesch/archive/2013/05/13/using-dmvs-to-monitor-and-terminate-long-running-mdx-queries.aspx

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions but 1) we have no control over the SSAS instance 2) we know which queries are long and don't want to cancel them. We've though of lightening the cube by removing a dimension...

Answer (score 0):

`ForceCommitTimeOut` property of *SSAS Tabular Model* is similar to the property in the multi dimensional model. These proerties are in milliseconds, so you can reproduce this issue in a functional environment by bringing down the value to *1000ms*, which would mean 1 second. The solution to this problem is to increase the value in this property to 0, which would mean wait until a lock is released.

[image: ForceCommitTimeOut Property of SSAS Tabular model]